# Is there any benefit of using actionservlet over normal servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, jsp

I like to write a program in android and JSP that sent notification from web to android application. I hear that there are two types of communication is possible in Web to android. One is Using normal servlet and actionservlet and other is using Web service communication. So i like to know that is there actionservlet have any advantage over normal servlet communication in android programming.